# I get a com3 error when trying to tun my raspberry pi pico in thonny

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

So I was trying to code with my raspberry pi pico. I loaded up thonny (with micropython) and I get this error.

```
Unable to connect to COM3: port not found

Backend terminated or disconnected. Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart.
```

The only reason I think this would happen was I tested the pi on a battery pack (using it somewhere not near my computer, or another computer, so it was necessary.) How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a battery pack, that tells me you don't have the Pico connected to the computer with the USB cable. (If so, it is dangerous to have 2 power sources without protection, like a diode.) Is that correct? If so, there is no COM port for Thonny to connect to.